# Update existing & published android app to Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have a published android app in the google play store.
I want to create the same app for iOS. After researching i found out, it´s best for me to use Flutter for future development, because i will have only one codebase for Android & iOS.

The existing android app includes a database (sqlite).

I want to rewrite the whole app in Flutter using the dart programming language, with the s**ame package name** and **same signing** from the existing app.

My questions:

- If i rewrite the complete app in Flutter, can i just update my existing app in the google play store
- If yes, will users loose the data in the database? is there a way to keep the data?

Answer (score 2):

For your first question yes, you can update your existing app, the process is easy if you have the previous app Keystore, you can use android studio to build a signed apk with the same way you signed it before,
for the second question, you might not lose the data if they just update the app without uninstalling.